Using signals/entities for multiple collections
Wanting to add multiple collections dynamically into the same signal store within an Angular app.
The use case I have is that I have a GraphQl backend through AWS Amplify. I was thinking of storing the receieved data for any query from the backend in a collection named with an unique identifier. This collection is used as a 'local store' for the front end presentation components. For this approach to be able to work then collections would need to be created dynamically - Is this possible - or indeed sensible?
Thanks
